# Can someone explain "Navigator.of" in Flutter?

Tags: android, ios, flutter

I am having trouble understanding what **Navigator.of** is and what it is used for. I have already read the documentation but the explanation is vague.

https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Navigator/of.html

Comment: there are a lot of information about Navigator, did you read this ?  https://medium.com/@kpbird/flutter-introduction-of-routing-and-navigation-49738dbd6abe

Comment: Hi Diego, I read it and finally figured it out! I had to look up "BuildContext" from the code example. By finding out what BuildContext class was, I figured out what Navigator.of does. Its kind of annoying how the documentation is not straight forward. I had to search around for other classes that interact with it to figure what it does lol.

Answer (score 1):

In general, one Flutter project has one MaterialApp, one MaterialApp has one Navigator, and many Scaffold. Scaffold means page in flutter. so Navigator control the route between Scaffolds in one MaterialApp.

So Navigator.of(context) means find the (state of) Navigator in the MaterialApp by the context of Scaffold.

Answer (score 0):

I used when I want to go to other Screen and can't go back . In my case when you logout go to the login Screen .